# How do I add a page preview image to the admin panel that highlights the edited portion of the page?

Tags: entities

I'm working with a website that has multiple content types per page and when you are editing a content type instance, it's not clear where that information will end up on the page. I didn't make this website. The guy who will be maintaining the content isn't really tech savvy so I'm trying to make it as easy and intuitive for him as possible.

In the admin panel when editing a content type instance, there would be an image on the right side of the screen that would show an image of the page you're editing. When you click to edit a particular field, it would highlight the corresponding section of the website being edited.

I don't know a lot about modules but would it be possible to do this? If so, what hooks would I probably be using? I was thinking that the highlighting functionality could be done by changing the background-color of the website portion with css and then taking a screenshot of that and displaying it on the admin panel.